# php date functions

Tags: php, date

I've rarely touched PHP date functions,

and now I need to do the follows:

1. get current date,
2. get date of three days later
3. get date of three weeks later
4. get date of three month later
5. get date of three years later

and finally to implement such a function:

```
function dage_generate($number,$unit)
{

}
```

`$unit` can be day/week/month/years

Comment: Could you please check the PHP manual and a search engine before asking any further questions. You seem to open a question for any bit of a problem. And we’re not here to do the lookup for you.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes, but part of the point of StackOverflow is to create a central repository of answers to questions that developers have.  The vast majority of questions here on SO can be answered by Google, but it may be that the asker doesn't know how or where to look.

Comment: @Matt Lacey So we should all just start making questions to match every function in the PHP manual, as well as every other language's documentation, so we can make this fully-comprehensive repository that is SO complete right? Kinda defeats the purpose. I'd rather teach someone HOW to use the manual than link them straight to the answer everytime. The old give a fish, teach to fish proverb...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://uk.php.net/strtotime can do most of that:

1. strtotime("today")
2. strtotime("+ 3 days")
3. strtotime("+ 3 weeks")
4. strtotime("+ 3 months")
5. strtotime("+ 3 years")

The function would be something like:

```
function dage_generate($number,$unit)
{
  return strtotime("+ ".$number." ".$unit);
}
```

Comment: It output pure numbers,but I need it in the format xxxx-xx-xx

Comment: internally dates & times are numbers. If you want formatting use the date funciton: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Shore: Then use the Date() function to convert those 'pure numbers' into a readable format.

Comment: date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+ 0 days")) is what I need finally.

Comment: Looks to me like strtotime("+ 0 days") might create some needless overhead. If you want the current date, you can simply leave out the second variable in the date() function.

Answer (score 1):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Note towards the bottom of the page:

Example #3 date() and mktime() example

```
<?php
$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"));
$nextyear  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) you can do this easily.

```
$now = time();
$threeDays = strtotime("+3 days");
$threeWeeks = strtotime("+3 weeks");
$threeMonths = strtotime("+3 months");
$threeYears = strtotime("+3 years");
```

Each of those variables will be an integer which represents the unix timestamp at that point in time. You can then format it into a human readable string using [`date()`](http://php.net/date).

```
echo date('r', $threeWeeks);
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date_create()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) to create a DateTime object, then use the [add](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method.

See the examples on the page for the add() method, they contain all you need.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Date/Time Functions with examples](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp)