# How to format date yy-mm-dd in PHP

Tags: php, date, format

I have dates currently in this format: **yy-mm-dd (e.g. 2011-11-18)**

I want them in this format: **Friday 18 November 2011**

I've tried reading through the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual, but I can't see how to manage dates in the format that I have. If the date needs to be in a different order I can arrange that, but I'm a bit stuck at the meoment.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php date functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471391/php-date-functions)

Comment: My question was specific to the given date format, so is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use PHP5s new date classes. Much cleaner:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2011-11-18');
echo $date->format('l d F Y');
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - >= 5.2 :-) (but I did think it was 5.3 also :-))

Comment: It is 5.3 according to the [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: @Jason: I don't believe in PHP < 5.3. :D

Answer (score 6):

```
date('l j F Y', strtotime($date));
```

Just use starttime to change the the dates in many formats using [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date('l d F Y');
```

gives you the date format you want.

This was all in the manual you yourself linked.

Answer (score 2):

just use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get back a timestamp and then use `date()` to format that:

```
$date = '2011-11-18';                  // your date
$timestamp = strtotime($date);         // convert to a timestamp
$new_date = date('l j F Y',$timestamp) // format timestamp
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: note that date() doesn't respect localization. use strftime() instead if you need it!